# openlayers padding white space

Tags: html, css, openlayers

I have excessive whitespace/padding in two places on two OpenLayers maps that I'd like to eliminate.

Here are the maps:

-- http://rainpursuit.org/map.htm
-- http://rainpursuit.org/mobilemap.htm

The whitespace that I'd like to eliminate:

-- the padding around the map.  I'd like to them to be full screen
-- the unnecessarily large popup windows.  The excessive whitespace isn't that big of a deal on the desktop version, but it leads to unnecessary panning in the in the mobile app each time a popup is opened.

I'm stumped here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset both the default padding and margin attributes in your CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

On the mobile version, you have in your mobile2.css:

```
.olControlMobileLayerSwitcher {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #CED6D9;
    display: none;
    height: 90%;
    left: 55%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

The `width:90%;` and `height:90%;` are causing the pop-up to be larger. You can change these values to decrease the height and width of the pop-up.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for your nearly instantaneous and effective response about the margins around the map.  As I expected, this didn't solve the excessive white space one the popup.  Anyone have suggestions?  Thanks again

Comment: Updated my answer in regards to your query